# Decode url(r'^(?P<pk>[-\w]+)/$') to path() in Django

Tags: regex, django, python-3.x, django-2.0

I need to convert the following regular expression using url() method to path() method.

```
url(r'^(?P<pk>[-\w]+)/$')
```

Thanks and regards.

Comment: `path('<slug:pk>/')`

Comment: very relevant question!! up

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try one of the patterns

```
path('<int:pk>/')
# or 
path('<slug:pk>/')
```